# Is there a continuous function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ which is a bijection on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ but not a bijection on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Is there a continuous function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ which is a bijection on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ but not a bijection on $\mathbb{Q}$.

I tried to argue in this way. Let $p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $f(p)=f(q)$ but $p\neq q$. Suppose $a_n\rightarrow p, b_n\rightarrow q$. Then $\lim f(a_n)=\lim f(b_n)$. But the limit case seems of no use.

Another idea is to prove $f$ is strictly monotone in $\mathbb{R}$, but I do not know how to begin.

Appreciate any help or hint!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want a continuous map $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $f \restriction_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}}$ is a bijection onto its image, but $f \restriction_\mathbb{Q}$ is _not_ a bijection onto its image?

Comment: Exactly. I want to prove such map does not exist.

Comment: If $f$ is not constant on $[p,q]$ then there is some $r\in (p,q)$ such that $f(r)\ne f(p)$ which implies that $f([p,r])\supset [f(p),f(r)],f([q,r])\supset [f(q),f(r)]$.

Comment: A proof along the lines of @reuns's comment is now in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420636/is-there-a-continuous-function-bijective-on-bbbr-q-but-not-on-bbbq