# Is there a continuous function bijective on $\Bbb{R-Q}$ but not on $\Bbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

**Question:**

Prove there does not exist a continuous function $f$ such that $f$ is a bijection on $\mathbb{R-Q}$ but not on $\mathbb{Q}$.

**My Proof:**

If there exists $q_1<q_2\in \mathbb{Q},f(q_1)=f(q_2)$, without loss of generality,we set $x_0\in (q_1,q_2),f(x_0)=\max\limits_{x\in[q_1,q_2]}f(x)>f(q_1)$.

Due to intermediate value property of $f$,

$\forall x_1\in \mathbb{R-Q}\cap(q_1,x_0),f(x_1)\in(f(q_1),f(x_0))$, there exisits $x_2\in(x_0,q_2),f(x_2)=f(x_1)$. $x_2$ must be in $\mathbb{Q}$ ($f$ is bijective on $\mathbb{R-Q}$).

So we have an injection from $(q_1,x_0)\cap\mathbb{R-Q}$ to a set of some rational numbers in $(x_0,q_2)$, which leads to a contradiction.

**My Question:**

1.Is my proof correct? Thanks for checking!

2.Are there any other proofs of the problem?

3.Can we construct such function ignoring the continuity?

Comment: I think you want to use the density of R\Q, not the density of f(R\Q), to justify the existence of x1.

Comment: I've just edited it to make it clear.Thanks for comments.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin :  Your link is back to this question.

Comment: You might want to write ‘without loss of generality’ instead of ‘assume that’.  The *assumption* is that $f(q_1)=f(q_2)$; it *follows* that $x_0$ exists. The only issue is that $f(q_1)$ might be the maximum value of $f$ on $[q_1,q_2]$, in which case you'd want to use the minimum to get $x_0$ instead; ‘without loss of generality’ covers this without suggesting that there's an additional hypothesis to the theorem.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what it means for $f$ to be bijective on some subset of its domain. Your argument seems to be only about injectivity; you use that $f$ is injective on the irrationals and prove that $f$ must be injective on the rationals as well. But a bijective function must also be surjective, and you ignore this. However, I'm not sure what the assumption about that is supposed to mean either.

Comment: The [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4141582/is-there-a-continuous-function-defined-on-mathbbr-which-is-a-bijection-on) was asked 10 months ago.

Comment: @TobyBartels Ooops, thanks. I just rewrote my comment with the correct link.

Comment: @TobyBartels : Sorry for the ambiguity.It's a question from a textbook(without answer) and that's the original expression.I guess it means "bijective to the image"(thus injective is sufficient).

Comment: @shdvt :  With that understanding, I agree with your proof.